# How do I map the path of a folder in ASP MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to map the path of a folder in my ASP MVC project from within another project in the solution. My model is in another class library. I have referenced System.web but I cannot seem to find Server.MapPath. <-- Im not certain this is the way to do this in MVC

So my question is: What namespaces need to be included in my model's project and how does one map to folder in the web application in MVC?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you're referring to is [HttpServerUtilityBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutilitybase.aspx) (typically called via Server.MapPath), but [HttpRequestBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.aspx) also has a MapPath method (typically called through Request.MapPath). These are part of ASP.NET 4's System.Web.dll. Note that the concrete implementations of these are HttpServerUtilityWrapper and HttpRequestWrapper. But in general, you would never create instances of those. Instead, use instances that you obtain from the ControllerContext.

The question though is why does your model project need to call this? You might want to avoid having your model have a dependency on these types. Ideally you'd just pass the value in when you create your model. Another approach is to create your own lightweight interface for locating file paths and have your model depend on that.

But not knowing why you need it, I can only speculate. :) If you have a good reason to use these classes, you'll need to pass in an instance of one or the other into your model class so it can call it.

Comment: You're right.. this value should probably be supplied when the model is constructed. I'm going to go that route. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to access it via HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath with the System.Web reference. Seems a bit bad to be putting this kind of stuff in your model though.

Within a controller you can use ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath.

Comment: Seems bad to have the model aware of the application folder structure?

Comment: Ultimately.. It think you are right. This is not the right place to be accessing the HTTPContext. +1

Answer (score 1):

It is in `Controller.Server`.  I'm not certain if the context will be set up correctly if you do not pass this reference along to where ever it is needed.  Alternatively, you could just map the path in the controller and pass the path to whatever needs to consume it.